# Change URL data on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

Hello I have a small website where data is passed between pages over URL.
My question is can someone break into it and make it pass the same data always?

For example let say, when you click button one, page below is loaded.

```
example.com?clicked=5
```

Then at that page I take value 5 and get some more data from user through a form. Then pass all the data to a third page. In this page data is entered to a database. While I observe collected data I saw some unusual combinations of records. How can I verify this?

Comment: HTTP is stateless. So the only way to verify is to check it again when the user sends in their data. For example, if clicked=5 should only accept some type of data, then you'll need to validate it once again on the server's end.

Comment: How can I do that? You suggest to use sessions?

Comment: No, you need to determine what is an "unusual combo of a record". Is it because when clicked=5 will only allow 5 textbox entries and the user submitted 6 entries? Then, from your code you need to check how many entries and if it's valid with clicked=?. If you're asking how to prevent people from manually changing clicked=? or detecting when they do -- it's impossible (There's referrer, but let's not go down that path).

Comment: Okay then, can a user do something to change all the data like doing it manually? If some one do that no one will be able to send any other button click event but the button defined by that hacker. This might be stupid but I am somewhat curious.

Comment: Not unless you have code that changes your existing PHP/HTML from user input or another security hole. From the code above, there's not a chance a user can make it so that everyone is forced to send the same button click event. I'm still confused what the question is, but there's two things that are facts. (1) clicked=*** can be set to anything, but ONLY for that user and (2) people won't be able to set clicked=*** for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. as javascript is open on the website, everyone can hack it.
you will need to write some code on you backend to validade it.

always think that you user/costumer will try to hack you sytem.
so take precautions like, check if user is the user of the session, if he is logged, if he can do what he is trying to do. check if the record that he is trying get exists.

if u are using a stand alone site, that u made the entire code from the ashes, you will need to implement this things by yourself.
like using the standard php session, making the data validation etc.
or you can find some classes that other people have made, you can find a lot o this on google. as it is a common problem of web programing.

if u are using a backed framework that isnt from another world, probably already has one. sp, go check its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<a id = 'button-one' name = '5'> Button One </a>
```

javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('button-one').onclick = function() {
     changeURL(this.attributes.name.value);
   };
};

function changeURL(data) {
 location.hash = data;
}
```

Comment: I am a beginner. So can you explain this a bit more? what happens on above code?

Comment: the first block of code. 

everytime ur document is loaded.. a event listener will be added to your <a> tag. that will make it trigger a function called "changeURL" with parameters on it. the parameter is the "name" attribute of the url. you can change it to anything you want. then manipulate it to the function "changeURL"

the second block of code is the function itself.

this is where you can do the coding.

location.hash is responsible for changing url. 

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

Comment: In this way no one can change the value passed?

Comment: you just need to add validation in the function changeURL. to check if it is a valid data. if not return false. to prevent from any hacks.